# Operator Overloading with different types

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Ok. So I'm trying to figure out how to implement an overloaded operator. I've searched some tutorials but there's something I'm missing. Maybe it's one of those 'obvious' things I'm thinking too hard about. I don't know. Which is why I'm here.

Here's the overloaded operator:

```
public static bool operator +(Hero h, Monster m)

    {
        if (!h.IsRunningAway)
        {
            if(h.AttackSpeed > m.AttackSpeed)
            {
                m.takesDamage(h.attackValue());
                if (m.isAlive())
                {
                    h.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
                }
            }
            else if(h.AttackSpeed < m.AttackSpeed)
            {
                h.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
                if (h.isAlive())
                {
                    m.takesDamage(h.attackValue());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                h.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
                m.takesDamage(h.attackValue());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(h.AttackSpeed <= m.AttackSpeed)
            {
                h.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
            }              
        }
        h.IsRunningAway = false;
        return h.isAlive();
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to implement this in a button click event in a form.

```
 private void btnAttack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Tutorials I've seen aren't being particularly clear on how to do it. Like I said, I maybe overthinking it. I usually do.

If the question can be edited to be clearer, or anything else is needed, let me know. I'm glad to edit.

Comment: Going to bed now. I'll check on comments in the morning and make whatever edit requests are asked of me then.

Comment: This is absolutely a horrible HORRIBLE abuse of operator overloading.  This is what methods are to be used for.  This will only create maintainability issues in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DO NOT*** use operator overloading here!

Operator overloading should be used when it makes sense. For example, the `-` operator can be overloaded on `DateTime`. When you subtract one `DateTime` from another, it makes sense to get a time interval:

```
25/4/2016 - 24/4/2016 = 1 day
```

But in your case, you want to do addition on a `Hero` and a `Monster`, *and* you want to return a `bool`! That makes no sense at all! Can you tell me what does this mean?

```
Superman + Godzilla = True
```

Even if you can, don't do it. Because others don't know unless you need to explain your code to them. This is a maintenance nightmare!

What you should do instead, is to write a method in the `Hero` class.

Just from reading your code, I think you want the hero to kill the monster when you use the `+` operator. And return whether if the hero is alive after the fight. So this method will probably do the job:

```
///<summary>
///blah blah blah
///</summary>
///<returns>whether the hero is alive</returns>
public bool KillMonster(Monster m) {
    if (!this.IsRunningAway)
    {
        if(this.AttackSpeed > m.AttackSpeed)
        {
            m.takesDamage(this.attackValue());
            if (m.isAlive())
            {
                this.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
            }
        }
        else if(this.AttackSpeed < m.AttackSpeed)
        {
            this.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
            if (this.isAlive())
            {
                m.takesDamage(this.attackValue());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
            m.takesDamage(this.attackValue());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(this.AttackSpeed <= m.AttackSpeed)
        {
            this.takesDamage(m.AttackValue);
        }              
    }
    this.IsRunningAway = false;
    return this.isAlive();
}
```

If you want to go one step further, you don't even need to return a value! Because the client code can call `isAlive()` to check whether he is alive, right? If `isAlive()` is private, make it public.

Comment: Thanks. That really is helpful. I was wondering about why an Operator Overload was wanted on this, too. But, that's what was required, so I've been trying to figure it out. Your method makes a bit more sense, though.